# Oracle copying the tree in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, tree

I'm looking for some interesting simple algorithm to copy (clone) part of the tree to another part of the tree.

We have a table:

```
create table tree (
     id integer not null,
     parent_id integer,
     value varchar2(255),
     CONSTRAINT tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );

begin
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (1, null, 'A');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (2, 1, 'B');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (3, 1, 'C');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (4, 2, 'BC');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (8, 4, 'BCX');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (5, 2, 'BD');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (6, 3, 'CA');
  insert into tree(id, parent_id, value) values (7, 3, 'CD');
end;
/
```

[image]

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fe802f144a3af0663754cfb3e8dc1ba

How to easily copy a tree "B" (ID = 2) with all children under "CA" (ID = 6)?

ORACLE 18-19c.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question. You want B to be included in CA? Is that right?

Comment: you want the children of ID=2 plus the ones under CA in ID=6 including CA ??

Comment: I want to copy the tree (B and children) to another place (CA) in the tree (in the table not in SQL)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question

Your original query provides this output

```
select level, id, 
       lpad ( ' ', level, ' ' ) || value name 
from   tree
start  with parent_id is null
connect by prior id = parent_id;

LE  ID  NAME
1   1    A
2   2     B
3   4      BC
4   8       BCX
3   5      BD
2   3     C
3   6      CA
3   7      CD
```

Then you say you want the tree "B" (ID = 2) with all children under "CA" (ID = 6)

```
select level, id, 
       lpad ( ' ', level, ' ' ) || value name 
from   tree
start  with id = 2
connect by prior id = parent_id
union all
-- tree to clone
select level, id, 
       lpad ( ' ', level, ' ' ) || value name 
from   tree
start  with id = 6 or id=7 
connect by prior id = parent_id;


LE  ID  NAME
1   2    B
2   4     BC
3   8      BCX
2   5     BD
1   6    CA
1   7    CD
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8e40541ac567ca588386aba6a524c22)

Comment: I want to copy the tree (B and children) to another place (CA) in the tree (in the table not in SQL)